# Router beforeEach guard executed before state loaded in Vue created()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

If I navigate *directly* to an admin guarded route, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/`, the navigation is always rejected because the state hasn't yet loaded at the time the router guard is checked.

`beforeEach` is being executed before Vue `created` and thus the currently logged in user isn't recognized.

How do I get around this chicken and egg issue?

*files below truncated for relevancy*

### main.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    //
    // This is executed before the Vue created() method, and thus store getter always fails initially for admin guarded routes
    //

    // The following getter checks if the state's current role is allowed
    const allowed = store.getters[`acl/${to.meta.guard}`]

    if (!allowed) {
        return next(to.meta.fail)
    }

    next()
})

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,

    el: "#app",

    created() {
        // state loaded from localStorage if available
        this.$store.dispatch("auth/load")
    },

    render: h => h(App)
})
```

### router.js

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('../components/Home.vue'),
            meta: {
                guard: "isAny",
            },
        },

        {
            path: '/dashboard/',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: () => import('../components/Dashboard.vue'),
            meta: {
                guard: "isAdmin",
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take `this.$store.dispatch("auth/load")` out of the Vue creation and run it before the Vue is created.

```
store.dispatch("auth/load")

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {...}

new Vue({...})
```

If `auth/load` is asynchronous, then return a promise from it and do your code initialize your Vue in the callback.

```
store.dispatch("auth/load").then(() => {

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {...}

  new Vue({...})

})
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you Bert!

Comment: @JeffS How would that work? Wouldn't that cause the issue OP is trying to solve?