# created hook not waiting for beforeEach action promise to resolve

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a `beforeEach` route guard that calls `fetchWorkspaces` action. This action performs a request to *Axios* and its response populates the state.

However, when the state is called from the `created` hook in the component and I refresh the page I do not get the values in the console, but the observer instead.

```
created() {
  console.log(this.workspace)   # returns {__ob__: Observer}
}
```

The action is returning a promise but the `created` hook is not waiting for that promise to resolve.

This is the hook from the router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('fetchWorkspaces').then(() => {
        next()
    })
}
```

And this is the action and its mutation:

```
export default {
  state: {
    workspaces: []
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_WORKSPACES(state, workspaces) {
      state.workspaces = workspaces.workspaces
    }
  },

  actions: {
    fetchWorkspaces({ commit }) {
      return Vue.axios.get('/workspaces').then(response => {
        commit('SET_WORKSPACES', response.data)
      })
    } 
  }
```

The `created` is called after the `beforeEach` hook. I do not understand why this behavior is happening and how to fix it.

The reason I want to get access the newly state data from `created` is to call other actions that will fetch resources based on this state data.

Answer (score -1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290003/router-beforeeach-guard-executed-before-state-loaded-in-vue-created) and [that](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/748#issuecomment-379299862). I think the Vue is created first before your router register `beforeEach`. So, you should use `beforeEach` before you initiate Vue instance.

Comment: I tried that before and it doesn't work. Same result. Declaring a promise should be redundant as from what I read in other places, Axios is already returning a promise.

Comment: Is it only happen when you refresh the page? When navigating normally it works ok?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. After the page is reloaded I can go back and forth through different pages in the app and I see it is displaying the state normally in the console. But that makes sense as the promise has been resolved already async and it is available by the time I click on the links. The problem is why is it not resolving when refreshing the page.

Comment: I think the answer you linked is referring to a different problem. I have access to the state in the router. What I don't have access in the component is the result of the promise defined in the beforeEach hook from the route.