# Vuex autologin with navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Hi im working with vue and vuex trying to set a navigation route so that the user is logged in automatically in case the token is still in local storage. Im getting a rare behaviour, if I check the value of a the getter that returns the variable called isauthenticated which is true if there is a valid token I can clearly see that the value is true, but when I get that value by it self it says its false.

```js
router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
  console.log(to);
  console.log(from);
  console.log(store.getters);
  console.log("is auth "+store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"])
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
    console.log("redirected to landing page")
    next('/');
  } else if (to.meta.requiresUnauth && store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
    console.log("redirected to home");
    console.log(to.meta.requiresUnauth);
    next('/home');
  } else {
    console.log("nexting")
    next();
  }
});

output:
{}
auth/isAuthenticated: true
auth/token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUz...."
auth/userId: "nHSQ3...."
user/username: ""
get auth/isAuthenticated: ƒ ()
get auth/token: ƒ ()
get auth/userId: ƒ ()
get user/username: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object

is auth false
nexting
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the navigation before each was running before my created() hook in my app.vue I fixed it by doing this:

```js
store.dispatch('auth/tryLogin').then(
  router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
      console.log("redirected to landing page")
      next('/');
    } else if (to.meta.requiresUnauth && store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
      console.log("redirected to home");
      next('/home');
    } else {
      console.log("nexting")
      next();
    }
  }));
```

You can read more about it here [Router beforeEach guard executed before state loaded in Vue created()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290003/router-beforeeach-guard-executed-before-state-loaded-in-vue-created#45290290)